# If with multiple and & or

Tags: vba, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I've been trying to run the below IF condition, however it does not work as intended:

```
If (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) = 1 And (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4) = 0 Or LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 5) = 0)) _
    Or (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) = 1 And ((LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4) - LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 7)) / LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4)) > 0.1) _
    Or (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) = 0 And LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 5) > 0) _
    Or (0 < LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) < 1 And (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4) = 0 Or LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 5) = 0)) _
    Or (0 < LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) < 1 And ((LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4) - LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 7)) / LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4)) > 0.1) Then
```

Those rows with 0 in `(LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6)`
and 0 in `LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 5)`

Are still applied in the IF function.

Comment: Use `Select Case` instead

Comment: You will need to specify with an example, as I am not very good with VBA

Comment: This: `0 < LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) < 1 ` does not work in vba and will need to be split into two seperate criteria. `LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) > 0 and  LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) < 1`

Answer (score 0):

I would take a guess that you are using `Or` where you should be using `ElseIf` and so your logic is wrong. In that case, use `Select Case` instead - it's quicker and cleaner. Here's an example with the first 3 conditions and an `Else` clause - just add the other conditions as required.

```
Select Case True
    (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) = 1 And (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4) = 0 Or LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 5) = 0))
        '// Do Something
    (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) = 1 And ((LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4) - LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 7)) / LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 4)) > 0.1)
        '// Do Something
    (LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 6) = 0 And LandscapingDataRange(MailCounter, 5) > 0)
        '// Do Something
    Case Else
        '// Do Something if none of the criteria are met.
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get, what you want to achieve, but logic operator have an order, in which they are resolved, just like multiplication/division before addition/substraction.

Maybe that is the problem in your case. Before any `Or` is computed, all `And` are resolved. So you have to use brackets, if this isn't the order, you want it to be computed.

The precedence order in Visual Basic is Not before And before Or before Xor, and the same rules should apply to VBA too.